Closedness of conical hulls related to polyhedra
For $W$ a closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p \in W$ let
$$
W_p := \{p + \lambda (q - p): q \in W, \lambda \geq 0\}.
$$
Supposing further that $W$ is a "polyhedron" := a finite intersection of half spaces, is it necessarily the case that $W_p$ is closed?
In more detail let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the usual Euclidean inner product and suppose that there is a positive integer $k$ and $w_1, \dots, w_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c_1, \dots, c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $W = \bigcap_{j=1}^k \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle x, w_j \rangle \geq c_j\}$; we can take this instead of the previous verbal formula to be the definition of "polyhedron" for this problem.
Should $W$ happen to have an interior in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p$ be in that interior, it seems pretty clear that $W_p$ will be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence closed.  More interestingly if $p$ is on the boundary of $W$ and there is at least one $j$ such that $\langle p, w_j\rangle = c_j$, a short and easy calculation establishes that $W_p$ will be contained in $\bigcap_{j: \langle p, w_j\rangle = c_j} \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle x, w_j\rangle \geq c_j\}$, and my guess is that this finite intersection of closed sets would actually be equal to $W_p$ in this case, so that $W_p$ is again closed; but it does not seem as easy to prove.
This question arose from user "AlexanderPope" in chat, in the case where $W$ was the "unit simplex" $\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n: p_j \geq 0, \sum_j p_j = 1 \}$, where all of the above observations were made; the user said they were led to considering this question for that $W$ by reading some paper, but I do not know what paper that was.
It can be noted (as user "Thorgott" noted in chat) that if $W$ is a more general closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ than a polyhedron, it is quite possible for $W_p$ to fail to be closed even in the case where $W$ is compact; for example if $W$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $p = (-1,0)$, then the set $W_p$ is the open half plane $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x > -1\}$ together with $p$ and hence not closed.
For purposes of surfacing this question in web searches and the like, it may be of interest that $W_p$ appears to be a translate of the "conical hull" of the set $W - p := \{w - p: w \in W\}$, and the example just given of a situation where $W_p$ is not closed, appears in an equivalent form in the Wikipedia entry for "conical combination" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination.  Obviously the translation by $p$ that occurs in the definition of $W_p$ above will not affect whether $W_p$ is closed or not.
Related questions on MSE include Why the cone generated by a closed convex set containing the origin may not be closed?, in which it is observed that if $W$ is a closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0 \in W$ it is possible for $W_0$ not to be closed (and the accepted answer is an example where $W$ is not a polyhedron), and Closedness of conical hull of a polyhedral convex set, in which it is observed without proof that some textbook shows that the conical hull of a closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that does not contain zero is closed (where the closed and convex sets whose conical hulls are considered in this problem do contain zero).
